# Перенос строк длинного текста в Spinner

Tags: android, android-studio, android-spinner, android-ui

Есть спиннер с длинными пунктами. Как организовать перенос строк (чтоб каждый пункт списка выводился в две строки как в свернутом, так и в развернутом виде)?

```
Spinner sp1, sp2; 
sp2 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.sp2); 
spin21 = new String[]{getString(R.string.p3_12), getString(R.string.p3_13), getString(R.string.p3_14)}; // Длинные строки 
adapter21 = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spin21);
adapter21.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_sp‌​inner_dropdown_item)‌;
sp2.setAdapter(adapter21);
```

Comment: приведите примеры кода, как вы создаете спиннер с адаптером, пожалуйста...

Comment: `Spinner sp1, sp2;

....

sp2 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.sp2);

...

spin21 = new String[]{getString(R.string.p3_12), getString(R.string.p3_13),
                getString(R.string.p3_14)}; // Длинные строки

...

adapter21 = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spin21);
        adapter21.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

...

sp2.setAdapter(adapter21);`

Answer (score 5):

Вам необходимо поменять стандартные `layout` на свои (кастомные).
Добавьте в папку `res/layout` соответствующие файлы с разметками:

***multiline_spinner_item.xml***

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="false" 
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
        android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
        android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall" />
```

***multiline_spinner_dropdown_item.xml***

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/dropdownListPreferredItemHeight"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"/>
```

После этого переписываем строки, где вы создаете `adapter`.

```
adapter21 = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.multiline_spinner_item, spin21);
adapter21.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.multiline_spinner_dropdown_item)‌;
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Comment: @iSmoke если вам помогло, нажмите, пожалуйста, "принять ответ" и проголосуйте "ответ полезен"

Comment: Error:(11, 32) Attribute is not public. (at 'layout_height' with value '?android:attr/dropdownListPreferredItemHeight').

Comment: @iSmoke попробуйте так `android:layout_height="?attr/dropdownListPreferredItemHeight"`

Comment: Теперь компилируется нормально, но при открытии лэйаута с данными махинациями, эмуль пишет "В приложении таком-то произошла ошибка" В xml эта строка выделяется (не красным) и комментируется как "The resource @attr/dropdownListPreferredItemHeight is marked as private in com.android.support:appcompat-v7

Comment: @iSmoke добавьте в CheckedTextView в xml  `tools:ignore="PrivateResource"`